# C++ - Pointer to local variable in Google's exercise code

Tags: c++, pointers, local-variables

[Here](https://developers.google.com/edu/c++/cpp-in-depth#exercise-1-more-practice-with-pointers), in Exercise #1, there is a function `HardToFollow`:

```
void HardToFollow(int *p, int q, int *num) {
    *p = q + *num;
    *num = q;
    num = p;
    p = &q;
    Unknown(num, *p);
}
```

The second last line makes `p` point to `q` which is a local variable(copy of an argument). A pointer to a local variable.

Later, in the main function, the pointer passed as this first argument is used after the call. Shouldn't this be undefined behaviour? Shouldn't the pointer passed as the first argument be undefined after a call to `HardToFollow()`?

**Edit:** I understood that it's not undefined behaviour, the pointer itself can be changed without reflecting the behaviour to the passed argument, only the changes to the pointed value will be permanent.

Comment: There is a problem with the function, p is only a pointer, whilst you can change the content of the pointer in the function you cannot change what it points to and get that new address when you exit the function.  The solution to this is to change: int *p to int** p, then in your function to assign to the content: **p = q + *num;  *p = &q;  Unknown must also take **p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that all arguments by default are passed *by value*. That means the value of the passed expression is copied into the functions local argument variable. That also means that changing the argument variable (like say assigning to it) will only change the local argument variable itself, not the original value used when calling the function.

This is what happens here: Someone calls the `HardToFollow` function passing a pointer. The value of this pointer is copied into the local argument variable `p`. And any assignment to `p` itself will *only* modify the local variable `p`.

So no this doesn't lead to UB, it's perfectly valid.